# Multiprocessing use in callable function to optimize using scipy: multiprocessing gets stuck after a few optimization iterations

Tags: python-multiprocessing, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm stuck with my code that uses multiprocessing to calculate the optimization function to optimize in scipy. Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
from functools import partial
from scipy.optimize import minimize

a = 1

# len(x_list) can be thousands, hence the use of multiprocessing
with open("x.txt","r") as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    x_list = np.array([float(i.split()[0]) for i in lines])

target1 = np.random.rand(10*len(x_list))
target2 = np.random.rand(15*len(x_list))

def calculate_x(x,x0,a):
    quan1 = (np.random.rand(10)+a*x)*x0[0] + x0[1]
    quan2 = (np.random.rand(15)+a*x)*x0[0] + x0[1]
    return (quan1,quan2)

def main(x0,x_list):
    with Pool(24) as pool:
        result = pool.map(partial(calculate_x,x0=x0,a=a),x_list)
    return(result)

def cost_func(x0,p_list):
    quans = main(x_list,x0)
    quan1_list = np.vstack([i[0] for i in targets]).flatten()
    quan2_list = np.vstack([i[1] for i in targets]).flatten()
    cost = np.sum(numpy.square(target1 - quan1)) + np.sum(numpy.square(target2 - quan2))
    print(cost)
    return(x)

if __name__=="__main__":
    x0 = [1,1]
    print("Initial guess: " + str(x0))
    res = minimize(cost_func,x0,args=(x_list),method='Nelder-Mead',options={'disp': True})
    print("Solution found: " + str(res.x))
    print("Cost: " + str(res.fun))
```

The code runs for a few iterations and hangs without printing cost function values.

When interrupted the following message appears:

> File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
> return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
> File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 765, in get
> self.wait(timeout)
> File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 762, in wait
> self._event.wait(timeout)
> File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 558, in wait
> signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
> File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 302, in wait
> waiter.acquire()
> KeyboardInterrupt

I suspect there is a problem with my code that may cause a deadlock, or maybe a race condition or synchronization issue (although in my actual code, I don't have any file that may be accessed by multi processes at the same time). It is not a memory problem as I cannot see any surge in the memory when using 'top' system command line. After interrupted, 'top' shows that the python processes are still running which is very weird. I also checked the output files and cannot find any extremely large number that may cause the calculation to stop.

I would like to express my gratitude to anyone who can provide help.